# Duplicating and replacing field values on rows in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Not sure if this is possible in MySQL but I am hoping for some guidance or direction on the following.

Say I have a table as such

```
Col_1 Col_2 col_3
AAA   56    3
AAA   99    3
AAA   100   3
BBB   43    1
BBB   66    1
CCC   33    0
```

and I want to duplicate rows where Col_1=AAA, but replace "AAA" with "DDD" and set col_3 to 0.
i.e. after performing the appropriate command the table looks like

```
Col_1 Col_2 col_3
AAA   56    3
AAA   99    3
AAA   100   3
BBB   43    1
BBB   66    1
CCC   33    0
DDD   56    0
DDD   99    0
DDD   100   0
```

Doing some reading it appears "Select ... for update" may be a starting point but am relatively clueless how to construct such a statement that fits this scenario.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! thanks.

Note: Even though Col_2 is the only column I showed in this example that is left unaltered, in reality my problem has about 10 unaltered columns, but I have shown just one for simplicity; point is, a solution shouldn't be discussed that explicitly focus' on just one column being unaltered... hope that is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the UNION clause:

```
SELECT Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 FROM tablename
UNION
SELECT 'DDD' AS 'Col_1', Col_2, '0' AS Col_3
FROM tablename
WHERE Col_1 = 'AAA';
```

Comment: That will work however I need the result to be committed as the new table (i.e. inserted).